# Problem with Type safety in Mockito - mocked collection

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito, junit5

I try to mock a List-Collection with Mockito along jUnit5.

I try to mock the following collection:

`@Test
public void testMock() {
    List<Integer> listMock = mock(List.class);
}`

I get a warning in Eclipse:
"Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List ".

I tried to fix it, but I'm not sure if there is a structural problem with the mocking with the software framework? Is there a way to fix this warning at all or do I have to accept an unchecked conversion, when I do a mocking of collections?

I'm thankful for any clues.

Comment: You.shouldn't mock a `List` just make a test list with the data you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get around that problem of mocking parameterized types by using Mockito's `@Mock` annotation, e.g. like this:

```
class MyTests {

    @Mock
    List<String> listOfStrings;

    @BeforeEach
    void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMock() {
        listOfStrings.add("a String");
    }
}
```

That said, mocking a `List` usually makes not a lot of sense but I guess you've chosen this just as an example for any parameterized type.

If you are using Mockito's Jupiter Extension you can even get rid of the `initMocks()` method:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyTests {

    @Mock
    List<String> listOfStrings;

    @Test
    public void testMock() {
        listOfStrings.add("a String");
    }
}
```

This will require an additional dependency, though: "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.2.4" (or whatever version you are using).

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. I tried to get rid of the initMocks() method as you suggested. Do you have any suggestions for any solution approaches?

Comment: I added the version with MockitoExtension.